# Resolve the $ref in API response in UI pointing to internal $defs

Tags: json, parsing, jsonschema

I have the backend API response to the UI as below JSON where `$ref` in some objects points to the internal obj `$defs` somewhere in the same JSON

```
{
  "schema": {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "mongodb.name": {
        "title": "Namespace",
        "description": "Unique name",
        "type": "string",
        "x-name": "mongodb.name",
        "x-category": "CONNECTION"
      },
      "mongodb.hosts": {
        "title": "Hosts",
        "description": "The hostname",
        "type": "string",
        "x-name": "mongodb.hosts",
        "x-category": "CONNECTION"
      },
      "data_shape": {
        "type": "object",
        "additionalProperties": false,
        "properties": {
          "key": {
            "title": "some data",
            "description": "xxx",
            "x-name": "mongodb.hosts",
            "x-category": "CONNECTION",
            "$ref": "#/$defs/serializer"
          },
          "value": {
            "title": "some data",
            "description": "xxx",
            "x-name": "mongodb.hosts",
            "x-category": "CONNECTION",
            "$ref": "#/$defs/serializer"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "$defs": {
      "serializer": {
        "type": "string",
        "enum": [
          "JSON",
          "AVRO",
          
        ],
        "default": "JSON"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am trying to use this https://www.npmjs.com/package/@stoplight/json-ref-resolver npm pkg to resolve the `$ref` but it's not working correctly and remove the sibling fields like `title`, `description`.

Is there any other npm pkg handling it correctly for the newer Draft 2019-09 and later?

Comment: Why do you need to resolve it?

Comment: In order to access the `type`, `enum` and `default` readings for `key` and `value`

Comment: @Indra I think what they meant is, are you using something which doesn't support the use of `$ref`? Many reference resolving tools are only partially working, and ultimatly not all references can be removed (or inlined). (Derencing is the act of determining the location being referenced). There is a defined bundling process, but it won't remove references, only allow you to compile multiple resources into a single document: https://json-schema.org/blog/posts/bundling-json-schema-compound-documents

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any mention in that package's changelogs about supporting JSON Schema draft2019-09 or later, which is what is necessary to be able to handle sibling keywords next to a `$ref`. In draft7 and before, `$ref` can only appear on its own in a subschema, not alongside any other keywords like `title`.

Comment: Technically, in draft 7 and earlier, if `$ref` is present all other keywords are to be ignored, but the `$ref` should still be processed.  Not sure what that impl is doing, though.

Comment: @Ether thanks for the pointers is there any other npm pgk handling it for newer drafts?

Comment: https://json-schema.org/implementations.html